# How to get a CSS selector in PHP?

Tags: php, css, selector

I am looking for a way to get a CSS selector in PHP. So say I have a string in PHP like

```
#something
{
   background-color: #fff;
   float: right;
}

// Some Comment with } and #
#some #some2 div#some3 .someClass
{
   float: left;
   color: #000;
}
```

Now I would like to be able to get all CSS selectors which have the property `float`. In this case I would like to get `#some #some2 div#some3 .someClass` as well as `#something`

Working with regular expressions however seems to be not possible since there is now way to tell exactly when a selector finishes. Do you have any idea how I could achieve this?

Comment: Have a look into: http://leafo.net/lessphp/ hope it be useful for you.

Comment: But that´s for Less, isn´t it?

Comment: yes. as I told you hope it be useful for you. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a library that parses CSS and gives you object oriented method to traverse throughout CSS file:
https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser

Comment: I kind of don´t get which file to include in my script. Simply the Parser.php? I am not using a composer.json...

Comment: Yes, downloading source code and including `/lib/Sabberworm/CSS/Parser.php` should work.